# MATLAB - Run webcam parallel to processing

Tags: matlab, concurrency, computer-vision, webcam

Hello and thank you in advance.

I am working on a MATLAB algorithm, using the computer vision toolbox, to detect objects from a live camera feed, displaying frames with bounding boxes on a deployable video player.

Due to limitations of my hardware, the detection will be slower than the maximum FPS delivered by the camera.

Now, I'd like to display the webcam video feed at maximum speed, not waiting for the detection to finish so that I will have a fluent output video with detections whenever they will be inserted.

Is there a way?

My first approach was to use the `parfeval` function to somehow run the detection parallel, but failed due to my lack of knowledge, how to give the frame to the detector and insert the resulting bounding boxes to the frame, "whenever they are finished".

Comment: that sounds too abstract. can you give some code examples maybe?

Comment: Sure, just like this: https://github.com/kbitr/matlab-yolov2/blob/master/yololive.m